# Convert recorded audio to wav file in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, wav

My question is that I would like to take recorded audio from matlab and convert it into a wav file. I know you would have to use the `audiowrite(filename,y,Fs)` to do the conversion but I am not sure how I would get the value of `y` from recorded audio.

A snippet of the code I am useing to record the audio is:

```
recObj = audiorecorder(Fs, 16, 1);

get(recObj);

%record audio for 3 seconds
recordblocking(recObj, 3);

myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback